# How to use Lucene to index data with EclipseLink

Tags: java, search, lucene, eclipselink

I'm working with EclipseLink as ORM.

I have an entity class name Book as folowed:

```
@Entity
public class Book{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String summary;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Authror> authors;
    public Book() {
    }
   ..............


}
```

And a class Author defined as followed

```
@Entity
public class Author {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;

   private String name;
   @ManyToMany
   private List<Book> books;

   public Author() {
   }

  // standard getters/setters follow here
  ...
}
```

I would like to use lucene to make a query to retrieve the list of books of an author having his name. for example, The list of books written by author named "Molière".

I found a way to combine lucene with Hibernate. but, i'm using Eclipselink as ORM.

Please does somebody know how to make this combination of Lucene and EclipseLink?